# Jquery retrieve XML data with same node

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, nodes

For example:

```
<school>
    <list>
        <name>Ali</name>
        <age>19</age>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>22</age>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>Marie</name> 
        <age>20</age>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>Anne</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </list>
</school>
```

How do I get the age of Marie or Anne?

I can get the age of Ali (with following code) because it is the first element:

```
var age = $(xml).find('age').first().text();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you want to be able to access by name: http://jsfiddle.net/SPu8T/

```
$(xml).find("name").filter( function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Marie"
}).siblings("age").text();
```

This if you want to access by index (where i is the index)...

```
$(xml).find('age').eq(i).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use standard javascript for this.

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('age')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Just change the index represented by i above to get whichever age you want.